# Disk usage (du) displays TB not MB

Tags: command-line-interface, du

I have an issue while running `du` that it does not display the usage in units of Megabytes (as expected with `-m` switch) but TB:

```
$ du -mhs /mnt/b
2.0T    /mnt/b
```

How can I get a more granular result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the  `-m` option by itself to display the disk usage in 1 Megabyte block units. Note that the disk usage will be displayed as an integer, i.e. only a number without a unit size.

The `-h` switch "overrides" the `-m` switch and will display the disk usage not in blocks of any size,  but in a human readable format, converting to GB's and TB's as needed. That number will include unit sizes like k, M, G, T

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the 'h'. That will convert everything to the most close size format, overwriting the other parameter.

So the proper command would be `du -ms /mnt/b`